# Dropdown List using LinqDataSource Formatting Issue

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linqdatasource

I have a dropdownlist which is bound to one of the LDS. Here is the code for that:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEntities" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="LinqDataSource3">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

And the code for LinqDataSource3 is:

```
 <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource3" runat="server" 
    ContextTypeName="Testing.DataAccess.TestingLinq2SqlVs1DataContext" 
    EntityTypeName="" Select="new (Name)" TableName="Entities" OrderBy="Name">
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

Now I am getting the values in this type:

> {Name = John}
>   {Name = Eric}

However, I want just:

> John

to be showed. Where should I make changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to specify the DataTextField.
Something like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEntities" runat="server"
   DataSourceID="LinqDataSource3" DataTextField="Name">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the **DataTextField** and **DataValueField** properties on the dropdown list